# iFrame on page, wait before all iFrame content is LOADED before showing iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Question explains everything.

I have an iFrame on a page.
I'd like to wait for the iFrame's content to LOAD completely before the iFrame is shown.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `completely` means waiting until all `iframe` DOM is loaded, then the easiest way which works fine for me is using jQuery:

```
$("iframe").ready(function() {
    $("iframe").show();
});​
```

Check the solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/YTGaT/

However, if you need to wait until all images/flash/etc in the `iframe` are *completely* loaded then I believe the solution won't be definite and successful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it doesn't work for what I want. I want EVERYTHING in the iFrame to be loaded. I'll note that the iFrame is another page on MY site. Is there any code that I can add to the page of the iFrame to make this work?

Comment: @HugoCornellier, Then you can try to add this code in your iFrame `$(window).load(function() { parent.$("iframe").show(); });` instead. So it should work in the opposite way: your iFrame will control itself via `parent` when everything is loaded.